# Transport to hotel from Cancún airport and back

Tags: airport-transfer, mexico, cancun, cun

I will be traveling to Cancún from USA. I am an Indian, this is my first trip to Mexico and I don't know Spanish. I am looking for ways to travel from the airport to my hotel. I have read through [wikivoyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Canc%C3%BAn#Get_in) and understand I have three options: Shuttles, Buses or Taxis and that pre-booked shuttles and buses are cheaper than taxis. My hotel (Sina Suites) doesn't offer any shuttle services.

I have found that [this website](https://www.cancun-airport.com/transportation.htm) offers hotel transportation which shows that a trip between airport and my hotel (Sina Suites) in both directions (round trip) is 65$.

[This](https://www.cancun-airport.com/transportation.htm) website (www.cancun-airport.com) and [this](http://www.cancun-airport.net/transportation.php) one (www.cancun-airport.net) seem scam websites as they look like they are Cancún airport's based on their URLs, the first one mentions the word "safe" too often, mentions the round trip when you pay ahead online is 65$ and when you pay it after arrival is $110, and thanks to [Numbeo](http://www.numbeo.com/taxi-fare/city_result.jsp?country=Mexico&city=Cancun) it looks like the taxi fare for a round trip would be around 95$. Hence these look like shady options to consider and better to rule them out.

What is the economical and safe way to reach my hotel from Cancún International Airport?

Comment: @pnuts From airport to Sina Suites is 26km. taxi fare for 26 km is around 45$ dollars based on [Numbeo](http://www.numbeo.com/taxi-fare/city_result.jsp?country=Mexico&city=Cancun). So two one-way journeys are 90$ and tip is 5$.

Comment: Any taxi would cost you around $500 mexican pesos without problem for that trip

Answer (score 3):

If by round trip you mean between airport and hotel in *both* directions then price seems reasonable given 483.67 MXN (currently about US$22) estimate at [Numbeo](http://www.numbeo.com/taxi-fare/city_result.jsp?country=Mexico&city=Cancun) (one way, before any tip). Hotel shuttle buses are generally reliable and cope well with luggage.

Answer (score 1):

The real site for the airport is www.asur.com.mx which is the company that manages the airport.

Be sure you get a reliable company for your transportation and most of all book this prior to arrival, I use [Cancun Airport Transportations](http://www.cancunairporttransportations.com)

Answer (score 0):

After some more research over the internet I found out about a Hotel shuttle company through [Trip Advisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g150807-d6419625-Reviews-USA_Transfers_Tours-Cancun_Yucatan_Peninsula.html), read the reviews and have booked their hotel shuttle service as the price was reasonable, looked safe based on the reviews and needed no paying ahead online and paying after I reach Cancun. I will update on how it works out.